# ignore last row of csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

We use `IGNORE 1 LINES` to ignore 1st row of CSV file. Similarly what will be the `IGNORE` clause in `LOAD DATA LOCAL` query to ignore last row of CSV file?

And one more question,what will be the query to include field at last row as given in this csv file http://temp-share.com/show/dPfsmgA5W

right now I've this php-mysql code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$url'
INTO TABLE buzz
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY ""
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Day,Exposures,Clicks,Earning,Ctr,Cpc,Cpm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
    $filename = "file.csv"; //set you csv file name

    $lines = file($filename);

    $count = count($lines);

    $count--; //decrease 1 to remove last line

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        echo $lines[$i];
    }
?>
```